# How to navigate to another viewcontroller from UITabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift4, swift5

How to navigate to another viewcontroller from UITabBar?
I am working on UITabBarController. Who have 4 TabBar Button and I have added a large Button on middle of UITabBar. So I want to navigate to new viewController when click on large Middle Button.

[image]

Actully I have added large button here Subclassing UITabBar(). I am giving you all code of UITabBar()
So Please tell me how can I do it. Rightnow everything is Working fine but only Navigateto new viewcontroller is Not working.

```
import UIKit

class MainTabBar: UITabBar {

    private var middleButton = UIButton()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupMiddleButton()
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if self.isHidden {
            return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        }
        
        let from = point
        let to = middleButton.center

        return sqrt((from.x - to.x) * (from.x - to.x) + (from.y - to.y) * (from.y - to.y)) <= 39 ? middleButton : super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        middleButton.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: 0)
    }

    func setupMiddleButton() {
        middleButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)
        middleButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        middleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 35
        middleButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        middleButton.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
        middleButton.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: 0)
        middleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(largeButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        addSubview(middleButton)
    }

    @objc func largeButtonAction(_ sender:UIButton) {
        print("Write your Navigation Code here.......")
       jumpToHomeVC()
    }
    
    
    func jumpToHomeVC(){
        let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeVC
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        nav.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        
    }
    
    
}
```

I subclassed my UITabBar() to my custom MainTabBar().

[image]

I want when I click on Large button go to new UIViewController and When click on Back again Come to UITabBarController means on Dismiss or PopViewController.

Or If is there any other solution to create a large button on middle of UItabBarController. click on anywhere in button to jump to new ViewController and on dismiss come back to previous controller.

Comment: What's the problem? If you want to navigate, navigate. How would you like to navigate? Where should the Plus button take the user? What sort of navigation should this be? Presented view controller?

Comment: Brother, When click on Middle + button (Large button). It should be jump to New viewcontroller.thats it.

Comment: Put break point and check if you do not receive  event then check your button's z index. I think your button is behind the tabbar items!!

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/SUITabView

Comment: No bro Event is Working fine.

Comment: Problem is not on Event, not on Button Action.Action is working fine. My problem is on How to jump to new ViewController. what should be the code to jump to new ViewController from UITabBar. Using Closer or Using Delegate or Anything.